# How to keep an image and text (vmax font) aligned when resizing browser?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I added an **img** and **div**(filled in like a circle or div-circle) next to the text using **bootstrap** and **view port units** (vmax font) in order to appropriately change the font size and image size as I resize the browser window while keep them aligned and displayed as inline.

Basically this is what I want to maintain as I resize the window:

[image: perfect sample]

However, you don't always get what you wished for...

**Problem:**  My problem began as I

- Added an image next to the h3 title
- Added a div-circle(div shaped like circle) next to the H1 and P Tags
- In the CSS I added `display:inline-block;`
- I also added `vertical-align:middle`

> **STORY:** So I started resizing the window and I realized that the
>   vertical align only works sometime, and the rest of the time it shifts
>   the text and images up or down. And when I make the window more narrow
>   it causes the image/div circle to push the text to the bottom. I don't
>   know how to solve this problem at this point. I just want to keep the image and text aligned no matter the size. So....

**How can I format my code to keep the images/circle aligned to my text as I resize the browser window?**

[Help Fix my Fiddle :(](https://jsfiddle.net/godsnake/wnn3r20o/1/)

**CSS:**

```
    h1 {
  font-size: 3.3vmax !important;display:inline-block;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vmax !important;display:inline-block;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2.5vmax !important;  display:inline-block; 
}

p {
  font-size: 2.0vmax !important;  display:inline-block; 
}

img {height: 2.5vmax !important; width:14.5vmax !important; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <row>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h3>Welcome to the main title of this page</h3>
            <img   src="http://www.useragentman.com/tests/pointerEvents/images/disney-tv.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="numberCircle">1</div>
            <h2 style="display: inline-block;">This is a main subtitle section of the page</h2>
            <p style="display: inline-block;" class="text-muted">The content here is far longer but smaller and remains muted.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="numberCircle">2</div>
            <h2>This is a main subtitle section of the page</h2>
            <p class="text-muted">The content here is far longer but smaller and remains muted.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="numberCircle">3</div>
            <h2>This is a main subtitle section of the page</h2>
            <p class="text-muted">The content here is far longer but smaller and remains muted.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="numberCircle">4</div>
            <h2>This is a main subtitle section of the page</h2>
            <div class="guestlist">
                <form class="guestlist-form" action="email.php#updates" method="post">
                    <input name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" type="email" title="Enter Email Address" class="guestlistfield" placeholder="Enter your Email" />
                    <input class="button" title="Enter Email" name="submit" type="submit" value="Add Email">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </row>
</div>
```

Any solutions or advice on how to solve this issue will be greatly appreciated. I need someone who's more of an expert with css3, and can guide me in solving this issue. **Thank you!**

Comment: Is a minor markup changed/adding a wrapper allowed?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question can you elaborate?

Comment: Is it okay to change your markup some to solve your issue?

Comment: Yes of course! You can change if it will improve the situation. Did you mean add a wrapper to wrap the img and text? If not just feel free to change it. and explain later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With  minor markup change, adding a `textwrapper`

```
<div class="numberCircle">1</div>
<div class="textwrapper">
    <h2>This is a main subtitle section of the page</h2>
    <p class="text-muted">The content here is far longer but 
</div>
```

and a new CSS rule, which is added to the `<div class="col-sm-12 flex-it">` element

```
.flex-it {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

The number will stay in place, [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wnn3r20o/2/)

What happens here is the `flex-it` class make the image and the text wrapper `flexbox` items, and the `align-items: center` keeps their content vertical centered.

The `textwrapper` keeps the text side-by-side with the image.

*Note, you need to fix the fourth number/text/fields so it behaves like the rest*

Comment: I figured it out using your solution, I didn't know I can use the display:flex; and honestly is the first time I have see the align-items property. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

if you cannot change the markup , position, padding and margin could do:

```css
/* BODY DEFAULTS */

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
@media (max-width: 210px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 211px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
/* CUSTOM FONT */

h1 {
  font-size: 3.3vmax !important;
  display: inline-block;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vmax !important;
  display: inline-block;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 2.5vmax !important;
  display: inline-block;
}
p {
  font-size: 2.0vmax !important;
}
img {
  height: 2.5vmax !important;
  width: 14.5vmax !important;
}
.col-sm-12 {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10vmax;
  background:gray;
  margin:0.25em;
}
.numberCircle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -3vmax;
  border-radius: 50%;
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);
  /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
  background: #333;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 818px) {
  .numberCircle {
    font: 86px Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 817px) {
  .numberCircle {
    font: 46px Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 417px) {
  .numberCircle {
    font: 26px Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <row>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h3>Welcome to the main title of this page</h3> 
      <img src="http://www.useragentman.com/tests/pointerEvents/images/disney-tv.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="numberCircle">1</div>
      <h2 style="display: inline-block;">This is a main subtitle section of the page</h2>
      <p style="display: inline-block;" class="text-muted">The content here is far longer but smaller and remains muted.</p>
      <p style="display: inline-block;" class="text-muted">The content here is far longer but smaller and remains muted.</p>
      <p style="display: inline-block;" class="text-muted">The content here is far longer but smaller and remains muted.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="numberCircle">2</div>
      <h2>This is a main subtitle section of the page</h2>
      <p class="text-muted">The content here is far longer but smaller and remains muted.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="numberCircle">3</div>
      <h2>This is a main subtitle section of the page</h2>
      <p class="text-muted">The content here is far longer but smaller and remains muted.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="numberCircle">4</div>
      <h2>This is a main subtitle section of the page</h2>
      <div class="guestlist">
        <form class="guestlist-form" action="email.php#updates" method="post">
          <input name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" type="email" title="Enter Email Address" class="guestlistfield" placeholder="Enter your Email" />
          <input class="button" title="Enter Email" name="submit" type="submit" value="Add Email">
        </form>
        <div id="error-message">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </row>
</div>
```